# What is going on in the following clause? ( 是非成敗謊言面對糾纏 )

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is taken from a song lyrics by AccuseFive.

> 我們都在愛裡面找答案
> 是非成敗謊言面對糾纏
> 時晴時雨 靈魂的一半
> 擁抱自我還容易簡單

Song lyrics are always vague, but in the second line I can't even identify what part of speech function each word fills.

> We both search for answers in love
> No matter if you're right or wrong, win or lose, lies bring us trouble
> A mix of sun and clouds, one half of the soul
> Embracing oneself is always easy

The translation is awkward and most likely completely off. I really don't understand what that second line is saying and what word fills what function. How should I parse it and what part of speech function does the words in it fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

中文已经成了意识流。当然，歌曲本来就是情感的宣泄，是意识流。所以，每个人的理解都可能不一样。要我来理解，“No matter if you're right or wrong, win or lose, lies bring us trouble” 这个翻译有些自作多情。原歌词更可能是表达情感带来的困惑混沌和矛盾，所以每一个词应该都是一个割裂的情感表达。强烈而矛盾。Right or wrong/ Win or loss/ lie/ confront(or not)/ tangled and pester。这也正好和下两段呼应起来。

Chinese seems to become a stream of consciousness or even subconsciousness now days. Not a communication tool with accuracy anymore (or, maybe never was?).

Hum...Of cause...singing is stream of consciousness naturally, since it is expression of emotion. Therefore, everyone might have different interpretation. From my understanding or interpretation to the lyrics:

"No matter if you're right or wrong, win or lose, lies bring us trouble", this is a wrong translation with pretentious. The song is more likely to express the frustration of relationship, and therefore each word should be representing a strong and conflict emotion separately:
是非：Right or wrong/ 成败：Win or loss/ 谎言：lies/ 面对：to confront (or not)/ 纠缠：entangled and pester.

Those echo the following lines as well: Sometimes sunny, sometimes rainy, oh the other half of my soul! Embrace myself (How about just lonely) would be rather simple and easy.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on the second line, since I am understanding your question as just asking about that.  This is an example of just using phrases in lyrics to convey the meaning with context, and the English you posted is fairly accurate.

是非 is literally "right and wrong", as a concept.

成敗 is literally "success or failure", as a concept.

謊言 is "lie(s)".

面對 is "confront/face(something)".

糾纏 is "tangled/entangled".

A more literal translation for reference would be "right or wrong, succeed or fail, lies (still) entangle (you/me/us)".

I'm not sure what part was confusing you.  If you were trying to parse the words all the way down to characters, that is a common beginner mistake and I don't reccomend it. Compound character words are more common overall.